# Raise ValueError for multiple if-else

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
if city == 'Chennai':
   print "this is Chennai city"
elif city == 'Delhi':
   print "this is Delhi city"
else:
   print "invalid city"
```

I want to raise ValueError whenever city is invalid. How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I refactored your code a little but it shows how to raise a [`ValueError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError):

```
def validate_city(city):
    city = city.title()  # Capitalize properly
    # use set(["Pune", "Delhi"]) for backwards-compatibility
    valid_cities = {"Pune", "Delhi"}
    if city in valid_cities:
        print "This is %s city" % city
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid city %s" % repr(city))
```

Sample output:

```
>>> validate_city("gotham city")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in validate_city
ValueError: Invalid city 'Gotham City'
>>> validate_city("delhi")
This is Delhi city
```

Notes:

- A set is used to look up valid cities, which is easier to maintain than many lines of if-statements.
- A set is [faster for lookups than a list](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).
- The [`title()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) method is used to capitalize the city name properly. It's good practice to normalize user input before validating it. I.e. turning "dehli" into "Dehli", "new york" into "New York" and so on.

Comment: It's working for me. Can you post the exact code you're running, including your test input?

Comment: If you're inside a `try/catch` block the error might be discarded.

Comment: Now it's a function that you can try yourself, I also updated the example with some sample usage.

Comment: Small point of detail but I would normally use set instead of list in this scenario as more efficient for lookups..

Comment: Even for very short lists/sets the set is ~25% faster, based on my mini benchmark using `timeit`, a set/list of two items and a failed lookup plus a successful lookup. If you only run this function once, it will only save you ~200 nanoseconds though - rewriting the function, benchmarking it, etc will take you much longer. Premature optimization is... fun.

Answer (score 4):

```
city = 'some city'

if city == 'Pune':
    print "this is pune city"
elif city == 'Delhi':
    print "this is Delhi city"
else:
    raise ValueError("Invalid City")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 8, in <module>
    raise ValueError('Invalid City')
ValueError: Invalid City
```

Comment: your code doesn't show me msg "Invalid City" when city is invalid

Comment: It will raise an exception. What does your script show?

Comment: Please check the edited post, and see if you are doing what I'm doing

Comment: i have used catch somewhere-else, thats why its not showing message

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you want to handlethe situation. However you would use the command

```
raise ValueError
```

at the point where you determine that this is an invalid city

```
validcities = ('Pune', 'Delhi', 'Any other valid city')

try:
  if city not in validcities:
    raise ValueError
  print 'This is', city, 'city'
except ValueError:
  print city, ' is an invalid city'
  # perform other invalid city here
```